# android phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can anyone please help me about how to fetch unique device id or serial number of android device. I have code for fetch device id of android device but I want code in phone gap framework means using jquery or javascript for fetch id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [device.uuid](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid) not fit your needs?